# Can't filter JSON-like thing

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, filtering, response

I'm writing an application in node.js, using data from https://swapi.co/. One of my functionalities requires to check whether specified planet exists in my db, when it doesn't, api should download planet's data from swapi, but somehow I cannot retrieve data about specified by name planet, I can only get data with format provided with this link: `https://swapi.co/api/planets/?format=json`

- when I try to filter or convert this result into JSON or filter it, nodejs gives me an error, but logging response's body in console shows that it looks pretty much like JSON, so, the question is how can I pull out specified planet response's body?

Method's code:

```
router.route('/Planets')
    .post(function (req, res) {
        var planet = new Planet(req.body);
        //validate planet.name here
        Planet.find({name: planet.name}, function (err, planet) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            if (planet == '') {
                console.log("action: planet not found");
                request.get(
                    'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?format=json',
                    {json: true},
                    function (error, response, body) {
                        console.log(body);
                    }
                );
                // planet.save();
                res.status(201).send(planet);
            } else {
                res.status(201).send(planet);
            }
        })
    })
    .get(function (req, res) {
        Planet.find(function (err, planets) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            } else {
                res.json(planets);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: it shows data so what is an issue ?

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/FlawlessNavyInterfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is JSON.
Planets stored in `results`.
So results it is array of objects, now you can go through all the elements of the array using `for` or `in`.

You can manipulate however you want, loops, filters, etc.

```js
fetch("https://swapi.co/api/planets/?format=json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    // Array of planets stored in res.results
    for (let i=0; i<res.results.length; i++) {
      console.log("Name:", res.results[i].name, "Data:", res.results[i])
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, this works like a charm, but I want to ask for another 2 things:
- how can I call functions from another js files inside fetch? After using them with require, all of my functions run right after compiling file?
- is there a way to access data from fetch outside of it's body: I want to take out specified planet, save it into DB and send it with status 201, but cannot do that inside fetch().